# Strip a response HTTP header when using Apache 2.4 as a reverse proxy for websocket

Tags: apache, http, websocket, proxy, header

I have a websocket server that works only in HTTP. In order to add HTTPS to it, I use Apache 2.4 in reverse proxy mode and it works great.

The websocket server insists on adding the X-Powered-By header that I would like to strip as I consider it a security concern. I'm already stripping it on the WAF but would like to strip it preemptively on Apache.

My Apache config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:1234>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      <stripped>
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   <stripped>
    ServerName              <stripped>

    DocumentRoot            <stripped>


    ProxyPass               / ws://127.0.0.1:5454/
    ProxyPassReverse        / ws://127.0.0.1:5454/


    ErrorLog                <stripped>
    CustomLog               <stripped>

    Header always unset "X-Powered-By"
 
</VirtualHost>
```

When examining the response headers to the websocket connection through Chrome dev tools, I found that the X-Powered-By header is still there. When trying to test things by adding a header through "Header add", I found that the wanted header is NOT there. As if the whole Header directive was ignored as far as ProxyPass and/or ws:// scheme were concerned.

Would appreciate any insights.

Thank you.

PS: I know NGINX would probably make this easier, but I'd like to continue using Apache.
PPS: Yes, mod_headers is active and adding a header to a non-proxied and non-ws Vhosts works perfectly.

Comment: This https://serverfault.com/questions/519845/why-are-http-headers-not-set-when-i-use-proxypass-on-apache2-2 for Apache 2.2, test it, it might still apply to 2.4.

Comment: Works for http:// proxy scheme, not for ws://